# open popup through Link in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I am Using Vaadin Framework in my application. I want to open a popup screen using Vaadin Link. I know to open popup thrugh button but I need to open popup through Link. Can anybody help, this is my code:

```
Link link1 = new Link(String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)), new ExternalResource("#")); 

_reportTable.getItem(dashboardDataRowId)
.getItemProperty("todo").setValue(link1);
```

Comment: why?  because of visuals?  most of the themes also have a button style, that looks like a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in in [Book of Vaadin - Components - Link](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.link.html), Link should be used only for hyperlinks to external resources, as it is nothing more than a wrapper for a anchor html tag and as such it does not fire any server side events. As a result you cannot react on server side to open a popup window or do some other logic.

> The Link is a regular HTML hyperlink, that is, an  anchor
>   element that is handled natively by the browser. Unlike when clicking
>   a Button, clicking a Link does not cause an event on the server-side.

What you really want is vaadin button styled as a hyperlink. You can do it by creating a regular button (which supoorts server side events and can open your popup) and then adding an appropriate style.

```
Button linkButton = new Button();
linkButton .setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
```

Always be sure to call addStyleName() instead of setStyleName() as it only adds your new style to the list of other styles already present and it does not override that list with your only new style.