# Vaadin Link Download

Tags: download, vaadin

Hi I am new to Vaadin framework.
Here I am using vaadin Links in my project I need to put a link for downloading files in my application I am unable to do this can any body send the code for hwich if I click the vaadin link then I am able to download the file in current step which is user uploaded in previous step.

Comment: FYI, for Vaadin 14, see the add-on [*File Download Wrapper*](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/file-download-wrapper) by Olli Tietäväinen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find detailed tutorial in this [official vaadin wiki article](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Letting+the+user+download+a+file).

> Providing a file for download to the user might be trickier that what
>   it seems - the file should be downloaded instead of just opened by the
>   browser, download blockers should be avoided, a unique URL should be
>   generated and server-side memory should be released when the file is
>   no longer available for download. All this is taken care of by new
>
> [FileDownloader](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc1/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader.html) extension that can make almost any component start a
>   download when clicked.

Comment: I am not using button for downloading. This URL of code contains Buttons.

Comment: Button is just an example component. If you read my post, you can see that "FileDownloader extension that can make almost any component start a download when clicked."

Comment: If you want user to see link, you should use button displayed as link, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047394/open-popup-through-link-in-vaadin

Comment: then why even bother with vaadin here?  place a `Link` there pointing to the `ExternalResource` representing your file.  or just style the button as link, if you are after the "visual"

Comment: Yes, you can do that of course. Depends on whether you want to react on server side to click event or not. With button you have opportunity to add additional logic. It you do not need that, link is enough.